# List files based on multiple search criteria

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

I'd like to search a directory listing for all files that either start with JL or NL, and only return those results.

I know I can do a ls -lrt JL* or an ls -lrt NL* but I need to know how to combine those in one statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `ls -lrt JL* NL*`?

The pattern is expanded by the shell, so it tastes exactly the same to `ls`.

If you're using `bash` you could also `ls -lrt [JN]L*` to create a single pattern that does what you want.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to using **character classes**, you can also use **brace expansion** to achieve the same results:

```
ls -lrt {JL,NL}*
```

or combining:

```
ls -lrt {J,N}L*
```

Both allow you to match multiple patterns and each have their benefits.